# Magento prepends script sources with document root after transfer

Tags: ee-1.13, media, magento-enterprise

I have moved my Magento install from one server to another, and everything seemed to go smoothly, but i am left with an issue...

Any and all scripts that are attempted to be loaded in (both frontend and backend) are prepended to be :

http://example.com/my/document/root/media/js/prototype.js ... which obviously doesn't exist... now i coudl creat a simple symlink in my folder, but i would like to find out how this has occured, since i have more then one magento instance, which i all would like to move to my new server.

I am NOT using combined scripts (yet) so i can see which are "missing" but it simply is all...

I have cleared my cache, and check read/write permissions on the media folder, and they are all correct (owned by webserver) o+w  (777)...

Any thoughts are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Follow below Steps.

**1.** Open your **core_config_data** table in phpMyAdmin.

**2.** Find the following rows for your **unsecure section**, they should look like the following:

PATHVALUE
web/unsecure/base_urlhttp://www.mydomain.com/
web/unsecure/base_link_url{{unsecure_base_url}}
web/unsecure/base_skin_url{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/
web/unsecure/base_media_url{{unsecure_base_url}}media/
web/unsecure/base_js_url{{unsecure_base_url}}js/

**3.** Replace **http://www.mydomain.com/** with your appropriate domain url (trailing slash necessary) and if you’ve installed in a subfolder append it with a / after it.

**4.** Find the following rows for your **secure section**, they should look like the following:

PATHVALUE
web/secure/base_urlhttps://www.mydomain.com/
web/secure/base_link_url{{secure_base_url}}
web/secure/base_skin_url{{secure_base_url}}skin/
web/secure/base_media_url{{secure_base_url}}media/
web/secure/base_js_url{{secure_base_url}}js/

**5.** Replace **https://www.mydomain.com/** with your appropriate domain url (trailing slash necessary) and if you've installed in a subfolder append it with a / after it. If you haven't received your security certificate and enabled TLS/SSL yet, use **http** instead of **https**

**6.** Clear **/var/cache**, **/var/session** after changing base_urls and when you have access to your system reindex your **URL_rewrite index**. Clearing cache and sessions is necessary because your config is cached and clearing it forces a reread of the configuration data from the core_config_data table and reestablishment of sessions with the proper information.

**NOTE:** IF YOU HAVE SET YOUR BASE_URL correctly for **web/unsecure/base_url** and **web/secure/base_url** YOU DO NOT HAVE TO MESS AROUND WITH CHANGING THE **{{UNSECURE_BASE_URL}}** and **{{SECURE_BASE_URL}}** MACROS in the rest of the entries.

This is going to definitely work.

Comment: I have checked my base urls, and they have the ending slash, which i know can be an issue, but that didnt solve it, and if that was wrong, it would still not display my document root path

And the second thing i did as well, i actually started with an empty var folder

Comment: you are something missing

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14044/tobias please join this room